Does the code in an OAuth2 Authorization Code flow ever hit the browser even in a BFF setup?
Imagine an OAuth2 Authorization Code flow with PKCE being done in a situation where a Backend For Frontend (BFF) sits between the browser and the Resource Server as described in OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps.
My understanding is that when the Authorization Endpoint returns the code it will be in an https 302 redirect response with the code as one of the query parameters. This means that the code will actually (for a short period of time) reside in the browser. Is that a correct analysis?
If yes will that pose a security problem, or are we saved by the bell due to the fact that the OAuth2 client (the BFF) must be a confidential client (the authorization server will simply reject exchanging the code for an access token if the code comes from an attacker)?
